# Advice on setting up my own DDNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind, nameserver, dyndns

Hello I've got a petproject running, creating a DDNS that is. I've read up on it but before I start buying resources and build, I was looking for some feedback on 
my current thoughts.

My basic idea is,

1)Buy a domain from a registrar

2)Create two subdomains at my registrar for my dns/nameservers ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com (apparently two seems mandatory?)

3)Set my custom name servers at the registrar to ns1.domain.com and the alternative to ns2.domain.com

4)Create two Linux VPS, setup BIND9/DNS.

5)At my registrar, point ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com to my VPSbased DNS servers.

Now if i've understood everything right, I don't have to bother updating anything else at my registrar and I can

1)Point my www.domain.com to wherever I want by editing my DNS records on my own DNS servers

2)Create and handle an 'unlimited' amount of subdomains by editing my DNS records on my own DNS servers. (So I can give users their own subdomain to change the IP for)

Is this correct or are any of my steps flawed, do I have to do something additional?

Thanks in advance for any advice or insightful information!

Answer (score 1):

Good summary and, yes, your plan seems fine.

Two name servers is indeed a mandate from the standard, RFC 1034. It is for resiliency reasons (if Sandy strikes one on the East Coast, the other on the West Coast will go on).

Also, BIND is not the only name server software, do not forget to check the others.

Answer (score 0):

The plan is fine, you can run a proper DDNS service that way.

One small remark, in case .com is just an example here and you plan on working under a different TLD. Keep in mind that although RFC 1034 requires that you keep your zone available on "at least two nameservers", many TLD-registries have stronger restrictions than that. For example, some TLDs require that those nameserver are located in different networks regarding the first two octets of their IPv4 address to be different. So make sure your VPS servers don't end up in the same /16 if you choose a TLD with such a restriction. Otherwise the registration of your "main domain" will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a pre made DDNS server package like GNUDIP http://gnudip2.sourceforge.net/ for Linux or MintDNS https://dynamic.domains for Windows Server(s). In either case a ton, and I mean a ton of work has already been done for you, and you can modify and dress anyway you might like. GNUDIP is free, and MintDNS is free for on commercial use.